# Vectors from a book

Tags: geometry, vectors

Ten years earlier I got a book about vectors. Here are three problems from that.

1. On sides $BC, CA$ and $AB$ of triangle $ABC$ points $A_1, B_1$ and $C_1$, respectively, are taken. Segments $BB_1$ and $CC_1$, $AA_1$ and $CC_1$, $AA_1$ and $BB_1$ intersect at points $A_2, B_2$ and $C_2$, respectively. Prove that if $\overrightarrow{AA_2} + \overrightarrow{BB_2} + \overrightarrow{CC_2} = \overrightarrow{0}$ , then $$\frac{AB_1}{B_1C}=\frac{CA_1}{A_1B}=\frac{BC_1}{ C_1A}$$
2. Quadrilateral $ABCD$ is an inscribed one. Let $H_a$ be the orthocenter of $BCD$, let $M_a$ be the midpoint of $AH_a$; let points $M_b, M_c$ and $M_d$ be similarly defined. Prove that points $M_a, M_b, M_c$ and $M_d$ coincide.
3. Given $N$ unit vectors in the space ($N>1$), prove that it is possible to select $N-1$ unit vectors such that the length of their sum is at least one (unity).

**My attempts:**

1. Summing up the equalities, we get $\overrightarrow{AB_2}+\overrightarrow{BC_2}+\overrightarrow{CA_2}$. From that $\overrightarrow{AB_2}=\lambda \overrightarrow{C_2B_2}$, $\overrightarrow{BC_2}=\lambda \overrightarrow{A_2C_2}$ and $\overrightarrow{CA_2}=\lambda \overrightarrow{B_2A_2}$. How should I continue?
2. Let $O$ be the center of the inscribed circle. Let $\mathbf{a}=\overrightarrow{OA}, \mathbf{b}=\overrightarrow{OB}, \mathbf{c}=\overrightarrow{OC}, \mathbf{d}=\overrightarrow{OD}$. If I could prove that  $\overrightarrow{OH}=\mathbf{b+c+d}$ where $H$ is the orthocenter of triangle $BCD$, then $$\overrightarrow{OM_a}=\dfrac{\mathbf{a+b+c+d}}{2}=\overrightarrow{OM_b}=\overrightarrow{OM_c}=\overrightarrow{OM_d}.$$

Comment: Can anybody help me?